# this sql made me little complex situation

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi sql'ers though am dealing with SQL  from past 4 years. I encountered little complex situation today.

I have a mysql table with columns, id,movieid,Lang,comment, and timestamp so i want to render comment for a particular  movie in which user can decide a range that from where to where he wants a  comment for that particular movie but when i try the following query will not working out. So help me guys  I'm stucked.

```
SELECT comment from aaa  where movieid=2 and language='en'  between6 to 10
```

Here basically I need to fetch from 6th comment to 10th comment from my aaa table (only for passed movieid parameter). All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I understand you need to fetch 4 comments in total (between 6th and 10th) so you want to use `LIMIT` for that, starting from 6th record:

```
SELECT
    `comment`
FROM
    aaa
WHERE
    movieid = 2
AND `language` = 'en'
LIMIT 6,4
```

Comment: Thanks @mitkosoft u saved my time... Works like 

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT comment from aaa  
where movieid=2 and language='en'  
comment between 6 and 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `AND` after the `language = 'en'`, also the proper syntax for `BETWEEN AND`

```
SELECT comment 
FROM aaa 
WHERE movieid = 2 AND language = 'en' AND (comment BETWEEN 6 AND 10 )
```